# Why is click event attached to className fired after className is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Related: [Jquery timeout for doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056183/jquery-timeout-for-doubleclick)

Given this code:

```js
function handleClick() {
  var div = $(this);
  var original = $(this).html();
  div.html("Tap again");
  $(".onlyfire").addClass("fire").off("click");
  $(".fire").one("click", function(fire) {
    alert("this should not be showing once the text is changed back to original");
    $(this).off("click")
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(div).html(original);
    $(".onlyfire").removeClass("fire").click(handleClick);
  }, 2000);
}

function onlyfire() {
  $(".onlyfire").click(handleClick);
};
onlyfire();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="onlyfire">
  Do Something
</div>
```

the `fire` `className` is removed from `.onlyfire` element following `2000ms`, where expected result is for `click` event which was attached to `.fire` would also be rendered inapplicable, as there would not be a `.fire` element within `document`.

However, as pointed out @120382833 at [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056183/jquery-timeout-for-doubleclick/39056256#comment65462153_39056256)

> Click on Do something, wait for 2 seconds until the Do Something is
>   back, Click again and it will show the alert.. And it shouldn't.. It
>   should display tap again and only if you click in first 2 seconds the
>   alert should show up.

To reproduce

1. Inspect `.onlyfire` element at `console`;
2. click `.onlyfire` element;
3. do nothing for two seconds;
4. the original text should be set back at `.onlyfire` element;
5. `.fire` `className` will be removed from `.onlyfire` element;
6. click `.onlyfire` element again
7. handler attached to `.fire` element is called, in turn calling `alert("this should not be showing once the text is changed back to original")`, though no `.fire` element exists in `document` at that point

Question: Is this a jQuery bug, or expected behaviour? Or, have we overlooked something within `javascript` which would explain result?

Comment: Your `.html(original)` is not replacing the initial `$('.fire')` divs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is expected behaviour.

Once an event handler is attached, the class changes made to that element do not influence the fact that the event will trigger the event handler. The class only plays a role in finding the element to attach the handler to. Once that is done, the class selector plays no role any more.

Comment: Are the details of this behaviour available at jQuery documentation?  Is the same true for `document.querySelector(".fire").oneventname` and `document.querySelector(".fire").addEventListener("eventname")`?

Comment: It is indeed not related to jQuery, but how the native DOM methods work. `querySelecor` delivers a matching element, and the `addEventListener` method or `oneventname` property act on this, without knowing even how you got that element.

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers are bound to *elements* not to their classNames. Static event handlers do not work like delegated event handlers.